# Tree addNode detect the root

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am creating a tree and learning TDD. I am not sure how I can detect the root here while adding node. Essentially I want 1 -> 2 -> 3 formed. I think thats how it would look in memory with my current setup. Obviously below test fails. (partly)

Test code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Nodes root = new Nodes(4);
    assertNotNull(root);

    root.addNode(5);
    root.addNode(6);
    assertEquals(5, root.printNodes(root)[1]);
    assertEquals(6, root.printNodes(root)[2]);
}
```

When I am adding a node, I want to add it to the root.

```
public class Nodes {

    int data;
    Nodes next;

    Nodes(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void addNode(int i) {
        Nodes newNode = new Nodes(i);

        while (newNode.next != null) {
            //detect root and add the newnode
        }
    }

    public int[] printNodes(Nodes root) {
        int[] n = new int[5];
        int i = 0;
        while (root != null) {
            n[i] = root.data;
            root = root.next;
            i++;
        }

        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your BT contains only one leaf? It is not a BT, it is a singly-linked list or somewhat similar.

Comment: I wanted to try getting 1 -> 2 -> 3 first and then the binary tree

Comment: If you want to identify root node from the child node, you will need to have a `parent` Node in each Node

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't a tree supposed to have a node array (if a regular tree) and two nodes (if a binary tree). This is more of a LinkedList, is it not?

Comment: its suppose to have a node array then. I wanted to start with a node array and then expand to binary tree

Answer (score 0):

```
root.addNode(5);
root.addNode(6);
```

With your current code, you don't need to detect what the root node is (you already have it with `root`), you need, instead, to detect the order of inserted nodes.

So your `addNode` could be something like the following:

```
public void addNode(int i)
{
    if (i == this.data) {
        // what do you do when data equal?
    } else {
        if (this.next != null) {
            if (this.next.data < i) {
                this.next.next = new Nodes(i);
            } else {
                Nodes tmp = new Nodes(i);
                tmp.next = this.next;
                this.next = tmp;
            }
        } else {
            this.next = new Nodes(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And then your `printNodes` function:

```
public void printNodes()
{
    Nodes tmp = this;
    while (tmp != null) {
        System.out.printf("%d\n", tmp.data);
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
}
```

This implementation is, of course, *not* a binary tree, but you've stated you are wanting to start with this implementation and expand from there, so I hope this can help you get there.